# Unable to track the logical error

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code:

```
if(!($rsContactList=mysql_query($sqlContactList,$con)))
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
else
{
    echo mysql_num_rows($rsContactList);
    while(($contact=mysql_fetch_array($rsContactList)))
    {
        $phone = $contact['telephone'];
        echo "<option value='$phone>'$phone</option>";
    }
}
```

I am getting number of rows more than one but unable to display. Let me know why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your query of $sqlContactList

Comment: Your option string has misplaced quotes

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching the data into an array. That means it just gets all the data and puts it in an array without looping. You might want to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` here, since that fetches the next row, executes your code and fetches the next row again.

```
while($contact = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsContactList)) { }
```

Or to prevent the `assignment in condition` errors:

```
while(($contact = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsContactList)) !== false) { }
```

---

You should not use `mysql_*` anymore however. There are better alternatives now, like [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). I use mysqli myself like this:

```
$rMysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

$sSqlQuery $rMysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");
while(($aRowQuery = $sSqlQuery->fetch_assoc()) !== false) {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
While(($contact=mysql_fetch_assoc($rsContactList)))
        {...
```

to

```
While($contact=mysql_fetch_assoc($rsContactList))
        {...
```